# I have two views on one cell, when I click on a cell it will be hidden and one edit form will be expanded on that. How to resolve that?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, custom-cell

I'm a beginner iOS. I have one cell of tableview with two custom views: one is item cell and one is edit form that cell. When user click on item, that item will be hidden and the edit form of that cell will be expanded on that.

How I can resolve that problem. Thank you!

```
(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    MinimumCell *cell1 = (MinimumCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MinimumCell"];
    if (cell1 == nil) {
        cell1 = (MinimumCell *)[MinimumCell cellFromNibNamed:@"MinimumCell"];

    }
    ExtendCell *cell2 = (ExtendCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ExtendCell"];
    if (cell2 == nil) {
        cell2 = (ExtendCell *)[ExtendCell cellFromNibNamed:@"ExtendCell"];

    }
    if(isEditClicked && selectedIndexPath.section == indexPath.section && selectedIndexPath.row == indexPath.row ){
        return cell2;
    }
    return cell1;
}
```

The default it will show cell1, when user click on that cell, cell1 is replace with cell2 (edit form). It is appear with expand animation.

Comment: do you have any code

Comment: I have just added my code

Comment: After clicking on the cell. you just need to call reloadData method.

Comment: @LeVanMan What happen when user click on cell2?

Comment: @V.J:Thank you.  Is that the best? Also, how do we can add animation for cell2 when it  is expanded

Comment: @Bannings: Cell2 is a form to edit information of cell1, so it doesn't have any thing happen when user click on that.

Comment: @LeVanMan You can insert the cell2 at bottom of the cell1 with expand animation like this http://i.stack.imgur.com/u9ilN.gif. Or replace cell1 with cell2 using `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use didSelectRowAtIndexPath on click of row to  reload that cell using 
  [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths: withRowAnimation: ];

Use your cellForRowAtIndex with following methods..

As shown below ,you can toggle between two  Cell view  using this method.

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

// isEditCell is bool variable used to toggle between cell types.

isEditCell=[self shouldToggleView:[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] ];

NSArray *ll=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:indexPath, nil];
[tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:ll withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];

}


-(BOOL )shouldToggleView:(UIView *)view {

while (view != nil) {
    if ([view isKindOfClass:[TableViewEditCell class]]) {
        return  NO; //[tbl indexPathForCell:(TableViewEditCell *)view];
    }else  if ([view isKindOfClass:[TableViewCell class]]) {
        return   YES;//[tbl indexPathForCell:(TableViewCell *)view];
    }
    else {
        view = [view superview];
    }
}

return nil;

}
```