# UITableView within UITableViewCell does not get updated

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have tried to create a custom cell that would display a list of items. To achieve this I tried to create a custom cell with `UITableView` inside it with scroll disabled.

The problem I have with this is when i try to apply changes to the cells in the inner `UITableView` data just does not get updated and the cell stays as it was. I have tried calling `[tableView reloadData]`, `[cell setNeedsDispaly]`, `[cell setNeedsLayout]` to no avail.

It seems like the data that has been applied when the cell was initialised persists through any attempts to change it. Though, when I create a breakpoint in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` the data does get updated but is not rendered.(e.g. `text` property of `UILabel` has new value, but text is old on the screen.)

Comment: Check that you don't lost the pointer to the UITableViewCell, probably you are sending messages to a nil object.

Comment: Can you paste how you create cell?( cellForRowAtindexPath method)

Comment: `CMRecommendedTableCell * cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"RecommendedTableCell"];

[self configureRecommendedCell:cell forRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

return cell;`

Answer (score 0):

You need to nil the cell and then reload the table view.  For some reason iOS caches table view data and stuff doesn't get updated correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You could try overriding UITableViewCell's `prepareForReuse()`: in that method you can set all the cell's outlets/properties to nil. You would do this for the cells in the main cell's table view. I am assuming those are custom cells as well and that you have a custom UITableViewCell subclass for them.

Comment: I am overriding `prepareForResue` on all custom cells, it has no impact. And yes, those cells inside are all custom as well with subclasses. It just seems that the UITableView inside the cell is cached once and not being redrawn for some reason. Even when the cell is reused.

Comment: Are you dequeuing the cells in `cellForRowAtIndexPath()` in the tableview class that represents the table inside the main cell? Something like `let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(identifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell`?

Comment: Yes, I was doing it this was. I have found a problem, and it is really stupid. i just redid the Interface builder outlets for the cells and it started working for no reason. Apparently, the there was something wrong with those, or xcode bugged out.

Answer (score 0):

Refer [[I have two views on one cell, when I click on a cell it will be hidden and one edit form will be expanded on that. How to resolve that?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31151853/i-have-two-views-on-one-cell-when-i-click-on-a-cell-it-will-be-hidden-and-one-e/31158890#31158890][1]) ..check in accepted answer methods ...

`[tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:ll withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic]` in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`